# Converting to Sparse_Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I wanted to use a Solver ecos for QP problem
and the thing is that this solver can't not acknowledge my matrix as a Sparse Matrix and I wonder how I should fix it.

So here is the Codes for Matrix settings

```
import numpy as np
matrixSize = 10  
Qa= np.random.rand(matrixSize, matrixSize) 
Q_1 = np.dot(Qa, Qa.transpose()) 
print(Q_1)
np.linalg.cholesky(Q_1)
p_1= np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10)
G_1 = np.diag(-1*np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10))
h_1 = np.random.uniform(-9, 9, size=10) 
np.savez_compressed(r'C:\Users\skqkr\Desktop\Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1', 
Q=Q_1, p=p_1, G=G_1, h=h_1)
```

and now the code for ecos Solver

```
import ecos 
import time 
import numpy as np   
from scipy import sparse 
Matrix10 = np.load(r'C:\Users\skqkr\Desktop\Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1.npz') 
start = time.time()

P = 2*(Matrix10['Q'])  # quick way to build a symmetric matrix 
q =Matrix10['p']
 
G_1= Matrix10['G'] ## sparsematrix?? 
G= sparse.bsr_matrix(G_1)  
 
h = Matrix10['h']
solution = ecos.solve(P,q,G,h) 
print("QP solution: x = {}".format(x))
print("time :", time.time() - start)

TypeError: G is required to be a sparse matrix
```

I used their sparse Matrix at the Variable G but it isn't acknowleged as a sparse Matrix How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I took time, (too much!) to clean up the code formatting of your question.  So why did you use `bsr_matrix`?  A guess?  Some documentation or recommendation?

Comment: The `ecos` documentation says it expects `CSR` format, but the code just uses `sparse.issparse`, for which `BSR` should be fine; then it converts the format to `CSC`.  It might help if you provided the full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `ecos` docs, the calling signature is

```
solution = ecos.solve(c,G,h,dims,A,b,**kwargs)
```

where `G` and `A` are sparse.

But you use

```
solution = ecos.solve(P,q,G,h)
```

Your `q` is in `G's` slot.  No wonder it's complaining.

Read, and Reread, the docs.  That should the first step, not SO.